# Checking script's arguments in a function

Tags: function, shell, if-statement, ksh

I am having difficulty trying to get an if statement working inside a function. I am using a very simple example like below to echo the $1 variable after script execution:

Logic inside script

```
STATUS() {

if [[ $1 == "-s" ]];then
   echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
   echo "Test success at: `date`:"
   echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
else
   echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
   echo "Test fail at: `date`:"
   echo "--------------------------------------------------------"
fi
}

STATUS
```

Example Execution:

```
ksh chris_test.sh -s
```

Expected Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Test success at: Sun Jan  7 06:59:34 GMT 2024:
--------------------------------------------------------
```

What I am getting:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Test fail at: Sun Jan  7 06:59:34 GMT 2024:
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I have attempted to escape the double quotes and the dollar sign, including the square brackets even trying to make square brackets single makes no difference. Still seeing fail. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Inside of `STATUS()`, `$1` does not refer to the script's first argument but to the function's. When you call the function you'll need to forward the script's arguments so it can read them.

`"$@"` does that. It expands to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...` for however many arguments there are, and with them properly quoted so spaces and other special characters are retained.

```
STATUS "$@"
```

Comment: What is also an option is using a variable for $1 outside function. For example. VAL1="$1". Within the function instead of working with $1, one will use "$VAL1" instead. I tested this and it works.

Comment: @ChristopherKarsten Maybe, but then your function wouldn't be easily reusable, like it would be with regular arguments

Comment: Fully understand. This would be a problem for dynamic variables mostly, but static should be fine and in my example the $1, $2..... are all static and are not subject to change